# Debian Stretch MariaDB cannot authenticate from PHP application

Tags: mariadb

I'm using a fresh installation of Debian Stretch, and installed PHP7 and MariaDB as recommended:

`sudo apt-get install nginx mariadb-server mariadb-client php-mysqli php7.0-fpm php7.0-curl`

Then using `sudo mysql_secure_installation` I followed the prompts to remove test users etc.

MariaDB seems to use unix_socket authentication (which is a new concept to me). I like how it restricts root access to sudoers and allows me to grant DB permissions to specific OS users.

However I'd prefer to assign individual user/passwords for each web application running on the server. They all run as `www-data` user on the system and I see no reason to let them share databases.

So I created a user for my first PHP script and granted access to a new database:

```
CREATE USER 'telemetry'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'yeah_toast';
UPDATE mysql.user SET plugin='mysql_native_password' WHERE user='telemetry';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON telemetry TO 'telemetry'@'localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

But it refuses to let me connect from the application:

```
[error] 19336#19336: *20 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Warning:  mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'telemetry'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in /path/to/database.inc.php on line 30
```

The credentials I'm using from the application are as follows:

```
Host: localhost (also tried 127.0.0.1)
Username: telemetry
Password: yeah_toast
Database: telemetry
```

I tried deleting and re-creating the username in case it was a password problem, and creating a user @'localhost' and @'%' but none seem to work. In fact when I log in using the same credentials from the command line without sudo it works great (`mysql -utelemetry -p`).

Am I missing a MariaDB configuration step here?

Comment: Does it connect if you use TCP/IP instead of socket?

Comment: @RickJames no if I connect to 127.0.0.1 (which I believe forces TCP/IP connection) I get the same result